# Would a square have more points than lines?

Tags: geometry, infinity

Suppose you have a square. Now, let $L$ be the set of all lines that can be drawn in the area described by the square, and let $P$ be the set of all points in all the lines in $L$.

Would the cardinality of $P$ be greater or less than $L$, or is this one of those times in which the infinite desecrates our logic?

Comment: Depends what you mean by size

Comment: @ZacharySelk fixed, I meant to say cardinality

Comment: Then both are $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but isn't a line defined by two points? How could the same amount of lines and points exist?

Comment: Well, just like that. Forget $\aleph_1$, it's too big for us humans. Think of $\aleph_0$: a rational number is defined by two integers, yet there are exactly as many rationals as there are integers. How so? Well, just like that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin $\aleph_1$ is **not** the same thing as $2^{\aleph_0}$ ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, sure. Let's say I implicitly assumed the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: To present a different viewpoint, in axiomatizations of projective geometry lines aren’t considered to *consist of* points. Instead, points and lines are classes of objects that have an incidence relation between them, such that for any two points there is exactly one line incident with both of them and vice-versa. This relation is completely symmetric, so in this framework there’s no particular reason to believe that there are more points than lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both have the same cardinality - namely, $2^{\aleph_0}$

(Note that contrary to what you may see in some popular mathematics textbooks, this is **not the same thing as** $\aleph_1$ - or rather, [the question of whether $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) is known to [not be answerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis#Independence_from_ZFC) from [the usual axioms of set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory).)

In response to your comment

> isn't a line defined by two points? How could the same amount of lines and points exist?

note that in fact every infinite set $A$ has the same cardinality as its square (= the set of pairs of elements of $A$)! This is an important difference between infinite and finite sets. Looking at [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) first might give you a good sense of how this can be the case.

---

A minor subtlety, which should be ignored until the rest of the answer is understood:

The statement "Every infinite set has the same cardinality as its square" is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice. So there's a reasonable question here: if we disallow the axiom of choice, *then* can we distinguish between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ in terms of cardinality?

However, the answer is still "no" - while the general fact requires choice, the *specific instance* we're interested in here is provable without choice. In fact, we can write down explicit bijections between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In full detail, these are somewhat messy; however, let me give a hint which will hopefully let you come up with one yourself:

- First, let's try the simpler task of finding a bijection between $[0, 1)$ and $[0, 1)^2$. This certainly doesn't seem any easier.
- Well, any element of $[0, 1)$ is really just a sequence of digits - its decimal expansion. So I'm really asking how to turn two infinite sequences into one infinite sequence.
- There's a natural way to do this: *interleaving*! E.g. I can combine the sequences $111111111...$ and $345345345...$ to get the sequence $$131415131415131415...$$ So my first guess at a bijection is: "interleave the decimal digits."
- Turns out that doesn't quite work. (HINT: think about things like $0.99999...=1$.) Can you see how to fix it? Can you see how to then get a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: "Note that contrary to what you may see in some popular mathematics textbooks" Out of curiosity, which popular mathematics textbooks say this?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Not many, but there is the occasional one. I believe Gamow had a book that did this, and there was some popular math book about set theory many years back that I read early on that got it wrong too.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/as1df0rbcl I found that the number of lines grows far more rapidly than points, but at infinity, I suppose that's irrelevant.

Comment: @script8man Yes, it is irrelevant when talking about the infinite situation. Analogously, note that the set of natural numbers and the set of powers of $2$ have the same cardinality, even though as we "count towards infinity" we seem to always be getting more of the former than the latter.

Comment: I believe the beth numbers were designed because of the problem taking $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ as equal. As I understand it, the latter equals $\beth_1$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Yes; more generally, the $\beth$-numbers are defined recursively as $\beth_0=\aleph_0$, $\beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}$, and $\beth_\lambda=\sup_{\alpha<\lambda}\beth_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ limit.

Answer (score 2):

The cardinality of the whole square is $\mathfrak c\cdot\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0+\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c $. So, $|P|=\mathfrak c $.

Now I wasn't sure if you meant *straight* lines or any (e.g. curved) lines, so I'll do the calculation for the latter. Each line in the square is a continuous map from $[0,1] $ to $P $, but it is uniquely determined by its values on $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1] $, so $|L|\le \mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c $. Because, trivially, $|L|\ge\mathfrak c $, you end up with $|L|=\mathfrak c$.

Thus, $|P|=|L|=\mathfrak c $.

Finally, I was not sure, when you said "points in all the lines" whether you wanted the points in the square to be double-counted (as they belong to multiple lines). Still *that* number is at most $|L\times [0,1]|=\mathfrak c\cdot \mathfrak c=\mathfrak c $ - the same cardinality again!

Comment: Note that you are using two facts here which the OP may not be familiar with already: that $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$, and more importantly that $a^b\cdot a^c=a^{b+c}$.

Comment: +1 for treating the curved line case - even more surprising, probably, than just $A^2\equiv A$!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Correct, and also $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ and $(a^b)^c=a^{bc} $, and also $a\le b \land a\ge b\Rightarrow a=b $ (Cantor-Bernstein).